# Symfony 2 - Layout embed "no entity/class form" validation isn't working

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I'm developing a blog in symfony and i'm stuck with forms that are embed inside the layout. In my case a simple search form.

```
<div class="b-header-block m-search">
    {{ render(controller('YagoQuinoySimpleBlogBundle:Blog:searchArticles')) }}
</div>
```

To render the form i'm using an embed controller inside the layout twig file.

```
public function searchArticlesAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchArticlesType());

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Do stuff here
    }

    return $this->render('YagoQuinoySimpleBlogBundle:Blog:searchArticles.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

The indexAction is the one that retrieves the form data and filters a list of articles.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchArticlesType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $criteria = array(
            'title' => $data['search']
        );
    } else {
        $criteria = array();
    }

    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YagoQuinoySimpleBlogBundle:Article')->findBy($criteria, array(
        'createDateTime' => 'DESC'
            ), 5);

    return $this->render('YagoQuinoySimpleBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig', array('articles' => $articles));
}
```

SearchArticlesType is a form class

```
class SearchArticlesType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('search', 'text', array(
            'constraints' => new NotBlank()
        ))
                ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
                    'label' => 'Buscar'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'searchArticles';
    }
}
```

The problem comes when i submit this form. The indexAction do his part, validating the form and filtering the articles but when the embed controller tries to validate data (just for displaying info or whatever)

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

I feel like i'm missing something.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `render(controller('your_route'))` you are actually making a sub request which means the parameters bags are emptied so your request isn't "handled" by the form.

If you are using 2.4+ you could get the master request from the request stack using ..

```
/** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $requestStack */
$requestStack = $this->get('request_stack');

$masterRequest = $requestStack->getMasterRequest();
```

And then you could handle that request in your rendered controller as opposed to the current (sub) request like..

```
$form->handleRequest($masterRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your: `public function searchArticlesAction(Request $request)` you're missing second argument on create form

```
$searchArticle = new SearchArticle(); // I assume this is how you named the Entity, if not just change the entity name
$form = $this->createForm(new SearchArticlesType(), $article);
```

Comment: Is a "No class form" like it's shown in the symfony documentation.

Thanks for your answer. :)