# Symfony embedded controller form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I've got a search form with some select boxes. I render it in the headnavi on every page using ebedded controllers. (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) 
I want to use the form output to redirect to my list-view page like this:

> /list-view/{city}/{category}?q=searchQuery

My form and the request is working well when I call the controller through a route, but unfortunately when I embed the controller, I'm stumblig over two problems. Like I've read here ([Symfony 2 - Layout embed "no entity/class form" validation isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973303/symfony-2-layout-embed-no-entity-class-form-validation-isnt-working)) my request isn't handeled by my form because of the sub-request. There is a solution in the answer, but its not very detailed.
The other problem, after fixing the first one, will be that I can't do a redirect from an embedded controller ([Redirect from embedded controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984429/redirect-from-embedded-controller)).
Maybe anyone has an easier solution for having a form on every page that lets me do a redirect to its data?

Many thanks and greetings
Raphael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of [Symfony 2 - Layout embed "no entity/class form" validation isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973303/symfony-2-layout-embed-no-entity-class-form-validation-isnt-working) is 100% correct, but we use contexts and isolate them, so an action which always uses the master request would break the rules. You have all requests (one master and zero or more subrequests) in the `request_stack`. Injecting `Request $request` into your controller action is the current request which is the subrequest with only `max=3` (injecting the `Request` is deprecated now). Thus you have to use the 'correct' request.

Performing a redirection can be done in many ways, like return some JS script code to redirect (which is quite ugly imho). I would not use subrequests from twig because it's too late to start a redirection then, but make the subrequest in the action. I didn't test the code, but it should work. `Controller::forward` is your friend, since it duplicatest the current request for performing a subrequest.

**Controller.php (just to see the implementation).**

```
/**
 * Forwards the request to another controller.
 *
 * @param string $controller The controller name (a string like BlogBundle:Post:index)
 * @param array  $path       An array of path parameters
 * @param array  $query      An array of query parameters
 *
 * @return Response A Response instance
 */
protected function forward($controller, array $path = array(), array $query = array())
{
    $path['_controller'] = $controller;
    $subRequest = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->duplicate($query, null, $path);
    return $this->container->get('http_kernel')->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
}
```

**YourController.php**

```
public function pageAction() {
  $formResponse = $this->forward('...:...:form'); // e.g. formAction()
  if($formResponse->isRedirection()) {
    return $formResponse; // just the redirection, no content
  }
  $this->render('...:...:your.html.twig', [
    'form_response' => $formResponse
  ]);
}

public function formAction() {
  $requestStack = $this->get('request_stack');
  /* @var $requestStack RequestStack */

  $masterRequest = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
  \assert(!\is_null($masterRequest));

  $form = ...;
  $form->handleRequest($masterRequest);

  if($form->isValid()) {
    return $this->redirect(...); // success
  }

  return $this->render('...:...:form.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView()
  ]);
}
```

**your.html.twig**

```
{{ form_response.content | raw }}
```

Comment: Hey Aitch, thanks for your detailed answer and code example! I did everything like you said, and render 'pageAction' on my base template.
Now im getting this error:
Variable "form" does not exist in ControllerViews/Renders/form.html.twig at line 1

Comment: as you can see from `formAction` we pass the `form` in `render()` and you can use it in `form.html.twig`. In `your.html.twig` in the `pageAction` you pass `form_response` which is HTML and you can just use it in twig. Please double-check that there is no `form` variable in `your.html.twig` and just try to understand what's going on in the controller actions to find the problem.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. In pageAction I rendered form.html.twig instead of your.html.twig. Now I'm getting the form, but it's still not working. I think it's still a problem with the request, because after submitting the form, the URL changes like this --> ?form[search]=Test&form[category]=&form[type]=&form[location]=&form[send]=&form[_token]=nQCbivIi7IppDpaWtmEesLOOVEoPL7njJCPpXPlxxPg

Comment: Look in the source HTML. is the method attribute of the form GET or empty? that's wrong, create your forms with `form_start`, etc. twig functions

Comment: <form name="form" method="post" action="">

Comment: So my form is passing data through GET while POST is given? Why is that? " if ($form->isValid() " always returns FALSE, caus its getting no data. I'm using the masterRequest... Calling my action through a route works just fine.. this drives me crazy..

Comment: okay, had a stupid mistake I didn't see.. placed my render controller into a form action... -.- nevermind, thanks for your help, everything is working fine :)

Comment: nice, that's great ;)